# Verifying a basic function with Lean4

Tags: lean, lean4, beginner

I have this simple structure to represent a person:

```
structure Person where
  age: Nat
  lifespan: Nat
deriving Repr
```

This function takes a Person and either (a) returns a "some" person with the age incremented, if they have not exceeded their lifespan, or (b) otherwise returns "none":

```
def agePerson (p : Person) : Option Person :=
  if p.age < p.lifespan then
    some { p with age := p.age + 1 }
  else
    none
```

I'd like to validate the function, but am having a hard time applying what I learned proving e.g., Natural Number arithmetic.

I would be grateful for someone to provide a theorem that works.

Comment: The `split` tactic (or the practically identical `split_ifs` tactic) can help when your goal state contains `if`s

Comment: While your original function contains p.age + 1 <= p.lifespan, it would probably make your life easier to use the equivalent p.age < p.lifespan.  (Otherwise, since this is a special property of natural numbers that these are the same, you have to find the lemma which converts from one form to the other, which looks to just be the definition of [Nat.lt](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Init/Prelude.html#Nat.lt).  Then you can rewrite with this lemma.)

Comment: @JasonRute - Thanks!  I've edited the question.  I appreciate the simplification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important thing to learn here is that dependent type theory allows you to state conditions which you cannot normally express in a mere programming language.

In the case at hand you should define `Person` so that it is *impossible* to create a person whose age is larger than the lifespan. One way to do this is as follows:

```
structure Person where
  age: Nat
  lifespan: Nat
  young : age <= lifespan
deriving Repr
```

We added a field `young` which is a proof of `age <= lifespan`.

Now if you want to make a person older by one year, you need the assumption that their age is strictly smaller than their lifespan.

Here's the first way to do it with tactics:

```
def agePerson1 (p : Person) (_ : p.age < p.lifespan) : Person := by
  constructor
  case age => exact (p.age + 1)
  case lifespan => exact p.lifespan
  case young => linarith
```

A second, more direct way:

```
def agePerson2 (p : Person) (_ : p.age < p.lifespan) : Person :=
  { age := p.age + 1,
    lifespan := p.lifespan,
    young := (by linarith)
  }
```

Example of usage:

```
def joe1 : Person := { age := 5, lifespan := 10, young := (by linarith)} 
def joe2 := agePerson joe1 (by simp)
#eval joe2
```

A typical programmer's instincts may be that it is "annoying" to have to verify `p.age < p.lifespan` before you can make a person older. But if you think about it, it's even more annoying to have to deal with `some ⋯` vs. `none`. And by explaining the rules to Lean, Lean will be able to *prevent you from making bugs*. You simply will not be able to write buggy code (altough you can write buggy rules).

Embrace dependent types!